# Convert input second into Month

Tags: java

Months are represented by numbers ranging from 0 to 11. For example, 0 is January, 1 is February, etc.
The code would be 
    double mon = (sec/2592000);
But how do I control the range from 0-11?

Comment: You need to add a context to the question, or at least more details.

Comment: Are you trying to get the current month from a unix timestamp? Each month has a different number of seconds so it is hard to do it with division alone but it definitely can be done from a unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mod` operation to control the range:

```
double mon = ((sec/2592000 - 1) % 12)   // from 0 to 11
```